# C# project with Interop.ComUtilitiesLib.dll issue

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-construction, open-source, runtime-error

I downloaded an open source project written in C# and I can build that project. However, I got the error like this during run time:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ComUtilitiesLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This means it couldn't load the Interop.ComUtilitiesLib.dll file, I have checked in project root directory as well as in the Window/System32, still couldn't find the Interop.ComUtilitiesLib.dll file.

Any suggestion for me to fix this problem!

Comment: I have tried to change the project's target platform to x86 but it still doesn't work for me!

Comment: If it builds, then that means they are dynamically loading the assembly at runtime. You need to look into the project documentation to find out what library this is and how to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the project include a `ComUtilities.dll` file? If so, it might be a COM object that needs to be registered via the command line:

```
regsvr32 ComUtilities.dll
```

Comment: Hi, the project doesn't include Comutilities.dll file!
I tried to run regsvr32 Interop.ComUtilitesLib.dll in both project folder and WinDows/System32 and what I got is " LoadLibrary failed- The specified module could not be found!

Comment: Looks like http://code.google.com/p/csexwb2/wiki/ControlRequirements has a downloadable copy but it might not be the same version or even the same DLL that your project is expecting.

Comment: I found the ComUtilities.dll in the /depends folder and able to run the command regsvr32 ComUtilities.dll. The message was the module has been loaded successfully but the issue still persists.

Comment: @MyticMoon I'm surprised that didn't work - usually this will resolve the reference in Visual Studio. I guess the last thing to try is in the project's references, delete the current Interop.ComUtilitiesLib reference and then manually add the Comutilities.dll you found as a reference.

Comment: Hi, I have resolved the issue since the Interop.Comutilities is missing then I have to download it and add it to the project folder. 
Thank you for your help :D